# ArrayList value changed to last element when accessing outside the loop in which values are added

Tags: java, arraylist, powerset

Actually I want to store all the distinct subset in the `res` ArrayList. I don't want to change the datatype of list, as it is required by some other method. The problem I get is the value of res is changed if accessing outside the loop in which it is adding the value. The changed value is the last value in the list which is copied to every position or something. Can anyone solve this error?

I also use `setlength()` to reset the value of string instead of delete.
When I use delete at last after entering value into list (after `res.add(counter)`), then all the values become empty and when I place `delete()` just after the initial for loop, then all the values in the list get updated to the last element value.

```
static List<StringBuilder> printPowerSet(int set[], int set_size) {
    long pow_set_size = (long) Math.pow(2, set_size);
    int counter, j;

    List<StringBuilder> res = new ArrayList<>();

    String temp = new String();
    StringBuilder sbFinal = new StringBuilder();

    for (counter = 0; counter < pow_set_size; counter++) {
        sbFinal.delete(0, sbFinal.length());
        for (j = 0; j < set_size; j++) {
            if ((counter & (1 << j)) > 0) {
                temp = String.valueOf(set[j]);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(temp);
                sbFinal.append(sb + "-");
            }
        }

        res.add(counter, sbFinal) ; 
        System.out.println(res.get(counter)); // the value here is displaying fine
    } 
    for (StringBuilder check : res) {
        System.out.println(check); // the values are changed here with last element value
    }
    return res;
 }
```

Comment: Make sure you follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names are written in camelCase. `set_size` should be `setSize`.

Comment: why are you using a `StringBuilder` and still doing string concatenation `sb + "-"`? And why a second builder `sb` ?

Answer (score 0):

You're always adding `sbFinal` to your `ArrayList`, so your `ArrayList` contains a large amount of only these.

Just replace by `res.add(counter, sb);` and relocate it to the place where it was created.

BTW: You really should consider storing `String` instead of `StringBuilder`.

```
static List<StringBuilder> printPowerSet(int set[], int set_size) {

    long pow_set_size =   (long) Math.pow(2, set_size); 

    List <StringBuilder> res=new ArrayList<>();

    for(int counter = 0; counter <  pow_set_size; counter++) { 
        for(int j = 0; j < set_size; j++) { 
            if((counter & (1 << j)) > 0) {
                StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(set[j])
                res.add(temp);
            }
        } 

        System.out.println(res.get(counter)); //the value here is displaying fine
     } 
    for(StringBuilder check:res)
    {
        System.out.println(check); // the values are changed here with last element value
    }
    return res;
 }
```